# Angular Directive showing message to all field, instead of showing message to specific field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs, I appreciate all the help I can get.

I have an angular form where user can create key value input fields. I am applying logic to check if that pair user have entered or not. If they have entered that then show message for that specific input fields only. However, directive shows message to every input field.

Thanks [image: problem]

```
function ruleValue(val){
    var code = scope.listOfValue[scope.index].code;
    var value = scope.listOfValue[scope.index].value;
    var idx = parseInt(scope.index);
    var list = scope.listOfValue;

    //compare code with code 
    // if code is same then check it's value 
    // if both same then throw an error 
    for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        if (i !== idx) {
            if (list[i].code === list[idx].code && list[i].value === val) {
                console.log(list[i].value, i )
                console.log(list[idx].value, idx)
                console.log(i, idx, list[i], list[idx]);
                ctrl.$setValidity('userRuleAlreadyExist', false);
                break;
            }
        }else{
            ctrl.$setValidity('userRuleAlreadyExist', true);
        }
    }
};

ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value){
    ruleValue(value);
    return value
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="userRule.type === 'maplist'">
    <label>Values</label>
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="v in userRule.values" ng-show="userRule.type === 'maplist'" >
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sub-list">Code:*</label> 
                <input name="code" 
                       type="text" 
                       ng-model="v.code" 
                       class="form-control"
                       placeholder="M"
                       no-special-char
                       user-rule-values-check
                       index="{{$index}}"
                       cv="code"
                       list-of-value="userRule.values"
                       required>
                <div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.code.$error"
                     ng-if="form.code.$touched && form.code.$error">
                    <div ng-messages-include="partials/includes/messages.html"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sub-list">Value:*</label> 
                <input name="value" 
                       type="text" 
                       ng-model="v.value" 
                       class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Medical"
                       no-special-char
                       user-rule-values-check
                       index="{{$index}}"
                       cv="value"
                       list-of-value="userRule.values"
                       required>
                <div class="help-block" ng-messages="form.value.$error"
                     ng-if="form.value.$touched && form.value.$error">
                    <div ng-messages-include="partials/includes/messages.html"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you share you html as well?

Comment: I have shared it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an `ng-repeat` within the form, so there are multiple `form.value` so when one of them has an error, the message will show for all of them.  You really want nested `<ngForm>` elements.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="v in userRule.values" ng-show="userRule.type === 'maplist'" >
  <ng-form name="rowForm">
    ...
    <input name="value"/>
    <div ng-messages="rowForm.value.$error" ng-if=rowForm.value.$touched && rowForm.value.$error">
      ...
    </div>
  </ng-form>
</div>
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Comment: No problem, I will suggest though that since you are new and starting out you might want to switch to [Angular2](http://angular.io/) now.